# Neutralizing the effect of variables before a clustering analysis

Tags: clustering

Working on a research project, I have 10 performance scores (scales, ordinates variables) for 100 participants. In addition, I have the age, gender (1/0) and education years of participants as variables. I also have a diagnosis variable, with 4 diagnoses.

I would like to find clusters in this dataset, assuming that some scores will allow to classify my participants according to the diagnosis.

I'm working with SPSS and use K-means clustering.
However, I cannot specify any nuisance covariates in the model, although I would like to neutralize the effect of age, gender and education in this classification (or prior to this classification). Put in other words, I would like to maintain age, gender and education constant while searching for meaningful clusters in my data.

Do someone know a good method that I can use with SPSS or Excel? I already reviewed some solutions written here but I frankly did not think that was appropriate responses (some looked interesting but did not imply SPSS unfortunately !).

Many thanks,
Ulysse

Comment: You should leave links to the solutions "looking interesting" to you. That may through more light on what you really wish.

Comment: Why not do cluster analysis separately on subgroups? Mind, besides, that clustering is not a classification, clustering does not have "predictor variables", to control for, like in regression.